# devcon.exe no devices disabled after everything that should have worked

Tags: command-line, command, devcon

I am having an issue where every time I try to disable a keyboard (and only a keyboard) it will not let me. I have tried everything and still nothing

C:\Users\x\Documents>devcon disable =keyboard
ACPI\LEN0071\4&166838075$0                                    :  Disable failed
HID\VID_413C&PID_2105\6&2B90921F&0&0000                       :  Disable failed
No devices disabled.

It should of worked but nothing has yet